# AngularJS Factory access this methods from returning object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, return, this, factory

I have created an AngularJS factory in which I'm returning an object which has some functions as properties. My purpose is to call some function in another function from that returning using the **this** keyword but its giving an error. I tried to console.log the **this** keyword and I found out that, that this variable holds the scope of calling controller in which the factory is being injected. How can I tackle this kind of situation. **this** keyword should return the current returning object!

```
 app.module('admin').factory('login', [function() {
return {
    someFunc: function() {
        return 'abc'
    },
    anotherFunc : function(){

        var msg = this.someFunc();
        return 'Msg is '+ msg;

    },
    yetAnotherFunc : function(){

        var msg = this.someFunc();
        return 'Msg is '+ msg;

    }
}
}]).controller(['$scope', 'login', function($scope, login){
    login.someFunc(); // Works Fine
    login.anotherFunc(); // Error : this.someFunc is not a function
}])
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the solution but have you tried binding this to it ?

Comment: You could also just define the functions outside the return statement.

Comment: binding this to it?? how

Comment: but I want to return those functions too.

Comment: You can you just define them so they get hoisted and return the reference.
like function bar() { console.log('foo') }; and then return { bar:bar}

Comment: there is an answer which will work for your scenario on your question here.  For a more general overview of why this is occurring, however, there is a widely accepted answer on the subject already.  This is not an angular issue, it is simply the way that closures work in JavaScript.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work/111111#111111.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
app.module('admin').factory('login', [function() {
    function someFunc() {
        return 'abc';
    }

    return {
        someFunc: someFunc,
        anotherFunc : function(){

            var msg = someFunc();
            return 'Msg is '+ msg;

        },
        yetAnotherFunc : function(){

            var msg = someFunc();
            return 'Msg is '+ msg;

        }
    };
}]).controller(['$scope', 'login', function($scope, login){
    login.someFunc();
    login.anotherFunc();
}]);
```

Now the `someFunc` will be visible in the scope of the returned object.

EDIT:

About the `this` issue, I think you're misunderstanding how `this` works in Javascript.

The `this` keyword will only work "properly" in certain circumstances:

- you're invoking a function on an object that was created using the `new` keyword
- you're invoking a bound function (see [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind))
- you're invoking a function using `call` or `apply` and giving it a context (this)

Looking at Waxolunist's answer, I can see that the code you posted in fact works, so you're probably doing something else that's causing the error. I'm guessing it looks something like this

```
$scope.yetAnotherFunc = login.yetAnotherFunc
```

This will "detach" `yetAnotherFunc` from its context, and that is why `this` is not what you expect it to be.

Comment: basically my comment :) but yeah thats it

Comment: I got you @pablochan . I was thinking about it as a solution but can you answer my query that why the returning object this keyword exhibits the $scope or this of the calling controller.

Comment: @ParamSingh I've updated the answer. I think the code you posted is not what you're actually doing.

Comment: Yes, I'm actually doing something like this in my controller .  $scope.loginFb = fbLogin.initLogin;

Comment: But I can't digest your explanation.

Comment: Yes its working after I enclosed changed the above thing. But how!! Can you please give me a little more explanation on it.

Comment: I'm at work, so I don't have enough time to explain it in writing right now. I suggest going through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution in a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/waxolunist/fcxu5eej/

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="LoginController">
        Get a Message:
        <button ng-click="someFunc()">someFunc</button>
        <button ng-click="anotherFunc()">anotherFunc</button>
        <button ng-click="yetAnotherFunc()">yetAnotherFunc</button>

        <div>Answer: {{answer}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('LoginController', function($scope, LoginFactory) {

    $scope.someFunc = function() {
        $scope.answer = LoginFactory.someFunc();
    }

    $scope.anotherFunc = function() {
        $scope.answer = LoginFactory.anotherFunc();
    }

    $scope.yetAnotherFunc = function() {
        $scope.answer = LoginFactory.yetAnotherFunc();
    }
});

app.factory('LoginFactory', [function() {
    return {
        someFunc: function() {
            return 'abc'
        },
        anotherFunc : function(){
            var msg = this.someFunc();
            return 'Msg is '+ msg;
        },
        yetAnotherFunc : function(){
            var msg = this.someFunc();
            return 'Another msg is '+ msg;
        }
    }
}]);
```

But I really doubt that a factory is the right thing to use. Maybe a service would be better suited. But basically your code works.

Comment: Doesn't it work for you in your browser or do you want an explanation? I don't know the rest of your code, but the snippet you posted is working.

Comment: $scope.loginFb = fbLogin.initLogin;  Its there in my other js file. That's why it wasn't working. The explanation  is in the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/6fwu7ghs/

HTML

```
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="testController">
<input type="button" ng-click="testFunc2()" value="test2" />
<input type="button" ng-click="testFunc1()" value="test1" />
</div>
```

JS

```
var testModule = angular.module('test',[ ]);
testModule.controller('common' , function(  $scope ) {
$scope.testFunc1 = function(){
    alert("test1");
    };
});
testModule.controller('testController', function( $scope , $controller ){ 
//inherit
$controller('common', {
    $scope: $scope
});

$scope.testFunc2 = function (){
alert("test2");
};
});
```

how about this way. I'm just using controller with 'inherit'

Do you really need to use 'Factory' ? then this is not an answer.